# Script bash chmod in a cicle

Tags: linux, bash

i want that script do a cicle when i introduce a dir and will ask each file i have there to change perm . why this output is always cant fin "file?" but the file exist

```
fucntion permi {

    echo "What is the path of the file? the introduce the name of the file:"

    read DIRECT

    file=`ls -l ${dir} | cut -f 9 -d " "`

    while read file
    do

        echo "[u|g|o]"

        read who

        echo "[r|w|x]"

        read ans

        chmod ${who}+${ans} $file

    done

}
```

Comment: could you please give example of input and expected output ?

Comment: exemple: i have in dir /tmp a file text1, he read the file and show the echo ugp and i write ug, then r|w|x  and i write wx , then do the chmod with the input i write like chmod ug+wx text1 @mebada

Comment: circle = iterate or loop .. please validate in your post to be clearer

Answer (score 0):

you may try this

```
fucntion permi {

echo "What is the path of the file? the introduce the name of the file:"
# read path from user with pattern .. eg (/home/mebada/test/* for all files, /home/mebada/test/*txt for all text files) 

read path 

# here I am iterating over the list of directory files .. no need to cut because I am just ls without ls long format (ls -l)
for myFile in `ls  $path`;  do
    # showing file current permission
    ls -l ${myFile}
    echo 
    echo "[u|g|o]"
    echo 
    read who

    echo "[r|w|x]"

    read ans
    #change file permission 
    chmod ${who}+${ans} $myFile

    # show after permission 
    ls -l $myFile
    echo 
    #Separator between two files
    echo " ---- "
  done
 }
```

Comment: Could you explain your solution?

Comment: Hi Robert I added comments ,,, anything else need to be clarified ?

Answer (score 0):

There are four major problems here. First, `ls -l ${dir} | cut -f 9 -d " "` does *not* generate a list of filenames. It picks out the 9th "field" from a long-format `ls` listing, but that might or might not be the filename, depending on exactly what `ls -l` prints. On my Mac, it mostly prints part of the date field. In general [parsing `ls` is a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and parsing `ls -l` is even worse. There are better ways to do it.

Second, the loop (`while read file`) doesn't do anything like what you want. What it does is read lines from standard input (generally, the that means it'll wait for the user to type something in), and puts what it reads into the variable `file` (which replaces the output from `ls -l ${dir} | cut -f 9 -d " "`). What you wanted to do was read *from* the variable `file`, not *into* that variable.

The third problem is that when working with the files you've found (e.g. `chmod`ing them), you need to supply the directory path *and* the filename, like `chmod ${who}+${ans} $dir/$file`.

But there's a better way that solves all three of these problems at once. Just use `for file in "${dir}"/*`. The wildcard will expand to a list of files in `${dir}` (including the directory path) without any of the messiness of dealing with `ls`'s output.

The fourth major problem is that you don't tell the user which file you're asking for the permissions to; the script just asks "[u|g|o]" and "[r|w|x]" over and over again, without saying which file it'll apply to.

I also have three minor suggestions: the `function` keyword is nonstandard; the more standard way to define a function is with parentheses: `permi() { ...`. Also, rather than `echo`ing a prompt for input, use `read -p` to print the prompt.  Finally, it's best to put double-quotes around variable references, to avoid trouble in case they contain spaces or some other special characters. With all these changes, here's what I get:

```
permi() {

    read -p "What is the path of the file? the introduce the name of the file: " dir

    for file in "$dir"/*; do

        echo "New permissions for $file:"
        read -p "[u|g|o] " who
        read -p "[r|w|x] " ans

        chmod "${who}+${ans}" "$file"

    done

}
```

Answer (score -1):

When I run `ls -l | cut -f 9 -d " "` I get some empty fields, some years or single digits. I'd recommend just using `ls` (without `-l`) to get the file names, since you seem to care only for the file names anyway, and not for anything else `ls -l` prints.

Then quote the file name when changing permissions (`chmod ... "$file"`), in case it has spaces.